# How can I substring a path in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a path that I want to clip off a leading section and use the remaining portion. Example path:

```
C:\temp\rootfolder\subfolder1\subfolder2
```

I want to be able to get just the `subfolder1\subfolder2` portion and I have the root folder as a variable.  Is there a command that I can take a path and apply a root path and get the remaining portion?

Actual Path: `C:\temp\rootfolder\subfolder1\subfolder2`

Root Path: `C:\temp\rootfolder`

Desired Path: `subfolder1\subfolder2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Replace` method on the string that contains the full path, passing in the variable that contains the root path (`$root` in my example), and empty quotes to replace it with nothing:

```
$root = "C:\temp\rootfolder\"
$path = "C:\temp\rootfolder\subfolder1\subfolder2"
$path = $path.Replace($root, "")
```

In this example `$path` will contain "subfolder1\subfolder2" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you close?

```
"C:\temp\rootfolder\subfolder1\subfolder2" -replace [regex]::escape("C:\temp\rootfolder\"), ""
```

Comment: This seems to be the most secure method. I even suggest another improvement: `"C:\temp\rootfolder\subfolder1\subfolder2" -replace "^$([regex]::Escape('C:\temp\rootfolder\'))", ''`. This makes sure that the replacement only occurs at the beginning of a path. Otherwise there might occur ambiguities in UNIX paths (e. g.: Path: `/home/user/home/user/subfolder`; Root path: `/home/user`).

Comment: Nice trick getting that anchor before the escaped bit. Not sure why, but it never occurred to me to just put it in a string like that. Doh.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
Set-Location $rootPath
$remainingPath = Get-Item $GivenFullPath | Resolve-Path -Relative
```